# MongoDB find with conditional project second param

Tags: mongodb

Let these commands present in the MongoDB shell:

```
> use testDB
> db.testCol.insertMany([ { score: 5 }, { score: 8 } ])
```

Now, I want to fetch all the collecrtion data, but with conditional projection with `find`.
So, let's say I want to include `score` field in resulted documents, only when the `score` value is greater than `6`.

Something (wrong) like this:

```
> db.testCol.find({}, { score: { $gt: 6 } })
```

My target result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("...") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "score": 8 }
```

How can I do it? Using only `find` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional operator `$cond` with [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields) starting from MongoDB v3.6, to remove field if condition not match,

- **MongoDB v4.4:** [projection consistent with aggregation’s $project stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection)

```
db.testCol.find({},
{
  score: {
    $cond: [{ $gt: ["$score", 6] }, "$score", "$$REMOVE"]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yUcyWHaAMyP)

- **MongoDB 3.6 or Above:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      score: {
        $cond: [{ $gt: ["$score", 6] }, "$score", "$$REMOVE"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VwWQ74lx9eW)

Comment: I get : `"Unsupported projection option: score: { $cond: [ { $gt: [ \"$score\", 6.0 ] }, \"$score\", \"$$REMOVE\" ] }"`

Comment: MY version is `4.2.7`

Comment: okay got it the $cond in find()'s projection would be support form mongodb v4.4, for this you need to use aggregate() i am updating my answer

Comment: No need. My version is not up to date. I just looked for most up to date answer.